# Error on start website in Server (IIS 7)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, web-applications

I have an aplication Web Forms ASP.NET Framework 4.0 with c#.
I published it and create in IIS (Web Server).
When I access this website, an error occur.

My app pool already set Framework 4.0!

Error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.

In my home.aspx, have an label with user name of windows.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FirstName = UserPrincipal.Current.Surname.ToString();
    string LastName = UserPrincipal.Current.GivenName.ToString();

    Label1.Text = LastName + " " + FirstName;
}
```

I use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

I can't use this authentication in IIS? In my localhost, work correctly

Comment: Check your application pool is setup correctly to use the .Net4 framework.

Comment: Richard. Yes! My app pool use Framework 4.0.

Comment: Have you configured the site to impersonate the authenticated user? If not, the `UserPrincipal.Current` will be trying to return the information for the AppPool identity.

Comment: ASP.NET Impersonation/Basic Authentication/Anonumous Authentication and Windows Authentication is Enabled! I need an specific configuration in my web.config?

Comment: If you have anonymous authentication enabled, there won't be a current user; all requests will be anonymous, and your code will be trying to return information for the AppPool identity.

Comment: Ok, Richard! Well, I have enable just ASP.NET Impersonation and Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Web.Hosting;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
   {
      string FirstName = UserPrincipal.Current.Surname.ToString();
      string LastName = UserPrincipal.Current.GivenName.ToString();
      Label1.Text = LastName + " " + FirstName;
   }
}
```

Also make sure you have windows authentication mode enabled and your app pool is running 4.0 integrated.

Comment: I implementing your suggestion, but, the error continues! ASP.NET Impersonation/Basic Authentication/Anonumous Authentication and Windows Authentication is Enabled, and AppPool already set framework 4.0.

Comment: @CaioVJesus89 You need to disable Anonymous Authentication.  See Richard's comment in your original question

Comment: Steve. Not work. The error continued! I accessed other pages, that no need get user (Windows Authentication) and they work normally, but very slow! You have an solution/suggestion? Tks!

Comment: Do you have impersonation set to true in your web.config file?  <identity impersonate="true"/>